# Display email in recipient's language?

Tags: email, internationalization

I'd like to send an email message that contains multiple translations. The correct translation should be displayed according to the recipient's language preferences. Possible?

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing in the email message format that will let you do that. What you can do instead, is to put translated contents as attachments, or post some (translated) links to your website, that will refer recipients to translated contents.

Anyway, I think it is best to store language preferences in the user profile (provided you have one) and use this information for customizing emails. That works well, unless you are sending messages to group of people...

Answer (score 0):

To the best of my knowledge, email accounts are protected from getting any information about the recipients unless they provide it. Even email clients often prevent emails from displaying pictures, since it reveals the recipient's IP address. So I also think, it's unlikely to be possible.

I agree with the idea of Pawel Dyda.